# Is it a good practice to JOIN a UNION result in outer query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a query and came up with a solution like this

```
SELECT a.c1, a.c2, b.c3, b.c4
FROM table4 AS a
LEFT JOIN ((
  SELECT c1, c2 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ... something
) UNION ALL (
  SELECT c3, c4 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table3 ... something
)) AS b

ON a.key = b.key
WHERE a.key ... something
ORDER BY a.key
```

This works perfectly as I want and not much execution time used. But it feels a little weird for me to have a result of `UNION` clause be in another `SELECT` and be `JOIN`ed with another table in a query.

So my question is : is it a good practice to use a query like this. Or I should find a better solution?

Comment: I would put `table4` first and use `left join` (a preference) and try to use `union all` instead of `union`.  We can't decide whether this is a good enough solution for you.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. My reason to put table4 after is only because I wrote the UNION first. Maybe I should change. -- UNION ALL seems to be a good idea, I haven't heard about it before. Edited question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is rather complex, but whether this complexity is needed for what you want to achieve, is not the question here. And we cannot answer this either, not knowing your table structures, real query, and desired results.

But as to the technical side: Your query is perfectly okay. If this is the most straight-forward way to get to the desired data, there is nothing against it. There is no rule that you shouldn't outer join a union result or the like. You just put your data together step by step, and if you end up with this query, then that's it.

As to UNION vs. UNION ALL, as mentioned by Gordon Linoff: It often happens that someone writes UNION instead of UNION ALL, thus unwillingly giving the DBMS more work to do than necessary. In your case, however, it may change the result, so you must consider whether duplicates are possible in your UNION query and whether you want them removed or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this, in my opinion its should be better

```
SELECT a.c1,a.c2,b.c3,c.c4
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b on ...
LEFT JOIN table3 as c on ...
WHERE something
ORDER BY a.key
```